# Microsoft Graph API Insufficient privileges when trying to update 'mobilePhone'

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

When trying to update (`PATCH`) a user's `mobilePhone` property using Application permissions, the response from Graph is "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation" (`Authorization_RequestDenied`).

Both the `User.ReadWrite.All` and `Directory.ReadWrite.All` permissions are granted. The access token is requested via the `client_credentials` grant (oauth2/v2.0/token endpoint) with specifying the `.default` scope and both permissions are present in the `role` claim in the access token.

Updating other properties works fine. The error is only when updating the `mobilePhone` property and only with application permissions (using the Graph Explorer with an admin user works).

This behavior suddenly started October 2. 2018. Before that, updating the mobile phone property also worked with application permissions (the same permissions).

As far as I can tell no new restrictions/required permissions have been added to the Graph documentation for user `PATCH` requests or the `mobilePhone` property. What could be the issue here?

NOTE: The requests are made using the Microsoft.Graph.GraphServiceClient (.NET Standard) but the same behaviour is also true when making the requests using Postman.

**EDIT:**

This is the response from the Graph API:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "Authorization_RequestDenied",
        "message": "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "e956cb0b-af0a-4bb7-aae3-59d39d007a82",
            "date": "2018-10-11T08:27:19"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Frankly sounds like a bug on Graph API's end, upvoted for awareness, the product does follow the microsoft-graph tag so hopefully they take notice to this :)

Comment: Indeed.  Can you please provide the client request id and timestamp that you should see in the 403 error response OR just provide the **full** error response.  This will help us take a look at the logs and figure out what's going on.  In theory, User.ReadWrite.All should provide enough permission to allow this change.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. @DanKershaw-MSFT I have edited the question - added the response

Comment: @DanKershaw-MSFT We see the same problem. The same application can set the mobilePhone field in the initial Create New User (POST) operation but it can not change or set it in a Update User (PATCH).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Our team had the same issue, we opened a Support Request with Microsoft and resolved the issue.

The solution is to add the **Helpdesk Administrator** role to the **Service Principal/Enterprise application**.

Microsoft changed the security policy on updating PII and changed the security roles allowed to update.

Here is more from our support request answer:

> The reason that this is occurring is because there was a recent change due to new PII sensitivity issues.
>
> So now you will need to add the Helpdesk Administrator role to the Service Principal/Enterprise application now.
>
> You can do this by following the article here : 
>   https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/aaddevsup/2018/08/29/how-to-add-an-azure-ad-role-to-a-enterprise-application-service-principal/
>
> This is to modify values such as : mobile/othermails/telephonenumber attributes.

Comment: Thanks for posting that workaround. To be clear, this recent change affects 3 specific user properties - in Microsoft Graph - businessPhones, mobilePhone and the soon to be released otherMails; in AAD Graph - telephoneNumber, mobile and otherMails.  We're also working on an alternative to running PowerShell to increase the permissions for the app.

Comment: @DanKershaw-MSFT -- are there any means of broadcasting these security changes to Azure AD admins?  It would be great to know about security policy changes in advance.  Thanks!

Comment: @DanKershaw-MSFT where should we watch to see updates re: alternatives to PowerShell? Reaching out to all of our customers who have already consented to allow our application to update their user profiles and telling them they have to go run some PowerShell to give us new permissions is not a great experience for us, or for our customers.